# Keeping messages in queue in case of receiver crash

Tags: java, spring, jms

We've a Spring JMS message listener container for receiving messages asynchronously. Using DefaultMessageListenerContainer and in sessionTransacted mode. I understand being in sessionTransacted mode means in case of an exception the message will be put back into the queue. But how can I make sure the message won't be deleted from the queue even if the receiver (which is picked the message) crashes or just the machine running it looses power?

At first I thought CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE acknowledge mode should save me, but [apparently](http://jira.springframework.org/browse/SPR-3796) it's not the case, Spring calls .acknowledge() no matter what.

So here's my question, how can I guarantee the delivery? Using a custom MessageListenerContainer? Using a transaction manager?

Answer (score 1):

Use a transacted session and indicate successful message processing  by invoking the `Session` class's `commit()` method.

Check the section [19.4.5. Processing messages within transactions](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/jms.html#jms-tx-participation) for the configuration. (you can use a `DefaultMessageListenerContainer`). Depending on what you're doing with the messages, you may need a JTA transaction manager.

Answer (score 0):

Spring message listener with Client_Acknowledge mode will acknowledge the message when the client calls message.acknowledge().

However, if after successful execution of the message, the consumer does not find any acknowledgement from the client side, spring assumes the execution was successful and acknowledges the message.

If at any point of time, consumer got an exception while processing the message, spring listener needs to know some exception has occured in order to redeliver the message to the queue for another consumer thread to pick it up. If you're catching the exception, spring assumes everything was handled and execution was smooth and hence acknowledges the message.

Spring message listener only allows to throw JMS exception from onMessage listener. Catching your custom exception and throwing a JMS exception from listener (after logging the error for future reference) will allow you to redeliver the message.

Answer (score -1):

or you can use Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE with nontransacted session,  see quote below from this [article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-02-2002/jw-0315-jms.html?page=3)

> A message is automatically
>   acknowledged when it successfully
>   returns from the receive() method. If
>   the receiver uses the MessageListener
>   interface, the message is
>   automatically acknowledged when it
>   successfully returns from the
>   onMessage() method. If a failure
>   occurs while executing the receive()
>   method or the onMessage() method, the
>   message is automatically redelivered.
>   The JMS provider carefully manages
>   message redelivery and guarantees
>   once-only delivery semantics.

Comment: -1 because the conclusion drawn from this document is incorrect.  Yes, there is redelivery if the receive() or onMessage() call fails but this does not mean the receiver has had a chance to do something with the message.  If the receiver crashes at this point, the message is irretrievably lost which is what OP was trying to avoid.  However, using a transacted session and explicit commit calls as described in the other response does prevent such loss of messages if the receiver crashes.

Comment: So in nutshell the article is misleading? What is meaning of crash? if onMessage method does not return due to crash wouldn't the message will be re-delivered?

Comment: I'm not saying the article is misleading, just that it doesn't apply to the original question.  All of the failures discussed in the article quote happen before the message is returned to the app.  OP wanted to delay message acknowledgment until after the message was returned and the app had processed it, as CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE is supposed to provide.  Setting Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE actually enforces the behavior OP was trying to prevent.